# Error trying to build pango (1.34.1) and harfbuzz (0.9.18) from source

Tags: source, sles

So I'm trying to build pango from source (in my home directory, as a dependency to something else I need). This is on a computing cluster running SLES 11. When compiling, I get the following error:

```
...
Making all in examples
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/people/xxxx/downloads/pango-1.34.1/examples'
  CC       cairosimple.o
  CCLD     cairosimple
/usr/people/xxxx/local/lib/libharfbuzz.so: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Advance'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [cairosimple] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/people/xxxx/downloads/pango-1.34.1/examples'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/people/xxxx/downloads/pango-1.34.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Checking the link dependencies on libharfbuzz.so gives me the following:

**ldd ~/local/lib/libharfbuzz.so**

```
...
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/people/xxxx/local/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f2323b0f000)
```

Going further, running an objdump on libfreetype.so (which I also installed from source) I get:

**objdump -T ~/local/lib/libfreetype.so.6 | grep FT_Get_Advance**

```
00000000000148f0 g    DF .text  0000000000000152  Base        FT_Get_Advance
0000000000014700 g    DF .text  00000000000001ed  Base        FT_Get_Advances
```

Though the version installed on the system, in /usr/lib/ (which I do not have root access to), has no references to FT_Get_Advance.

It looks like somewhere the code is referencing to the global library, though I can't seem to find where. Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** I just ran an objdump on libharfbuzz.so (from the version installed in my home directory) and it seems there are many undefined references to both freetype and GLIBC... So what's wrong with how i'm compiling harfbuzz?

**objdump -T libharfbuzz.so | grep *UND***

```
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Get_Advance
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 mprotect
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Load_Sfnt_Table
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 memset
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Set_Char_Size
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 snprintf
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Select_Charmap
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_intern_static_string
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_unichar_combining_class
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Load_Glyph
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              __gmon_start__
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __assert_fail
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strncmp
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 malloc
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000             g_unicode_script_to_iso15924
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Done_FreeType
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __cxa_atexit
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_unichar_get_mirror_char
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 sysconf
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_unichar_compose
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 pthread_mutex_init
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_unicode_script_from_iso15924
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 free
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strlen
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000                FT_Face_GetCharVariantIndex
0000000000000000  w   DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __cxa_finalize
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 bsearch
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Get_Name_Index
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Get_Kerning
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_unichar_decompose
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strerror
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strstr
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_unichar_type
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Init_FreeType
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strtol
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_unichar_iswide
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 memcpy
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 memmove
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strchr
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_unichar_get_script
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 getenv
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __errno_location
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 qsort
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strdup
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strcmp
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_New_Memory_Face
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 calloc
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Get_Char_Index
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strncpy
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_once_init_enter
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Get_Glyph_Name
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 pthread_mutex_lock
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 realloc
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              FT_Done_Face
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_once_init_leave
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 setlocale
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 pthread_mutex_destroy
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strtoul
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 pthread_mutex_unlock
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_unichar_fully_decompose
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_boxed_type_register_static
```

Answer (score 2):

2 Things:

1) Harfbuzz and FreeType apparently have an infamous circular dependency. This means you need to really need to do your own builds of both, and in a place totally isolated from the system libraries.

2) As a rule of thumb, the GCC build tools will find the system libraries before any customized builds of your own (e.g. via pkgconfig, FindXXX.cmake, environment vars, etc.) unless you explicitly tell them to look at yours 1st. That's the major use case they're aimed at, after all. Check that your CMakeLists.txt or Makefile is explicitly linking in your version of FreeType, not any OS one. It sounds like your build is finding the OS one 1st, then (incorrectly) trying to use it.

To test that you're getting the right FreeType, you could back yours up then alter the major version #. Re-run the build then run "ldd" or "readelf -d" on your build of libharfbuzz.so and confirm you see the right version of Freetype linked in.

As an aside, to build Pango to use Harfbuzz the order of operations appears to be:
A) Build "plain" FreeType 
B) Build Harfbuzz
C) Build new Freetype WITH Harfbuzz
D) Finally, build Pango with the FreeType in step (C), plus Harfbuzz explicitly.

I've not tried it yet, but that's the indication the various instructions are giving me. I might pass on Harfbuzz entirely unless you're sure you need it, since it appears introducing it implies rebuilding FreeType too.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough and thoughtful explanation! Sadly, I have since moved on from the position I was in when I had this problem, but I hope this can work as a reference for others grappling with circular dependencies such as this.